# Get associations when using getModel on another model sequelize

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

I would like include team association when getting teams by my user instance. I could not find way to do it.

```
const userTeams = await user.getTeams({
      joinTableAttributes: []
});
```

I tried do it by passing "include" like:

```
const userTeams = await user.getTeams({
    joinTableAttributes: [],
    include: { model: Board, as: 'boards', through: { attributes: [] } }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the association for `user` and `team` before calling the `getTeams` method on `User` model.

E.g.

`index.ts`:

```js
import { sequelize } from '../../db';
import { Model, DataTypes, HasManyGetAssociationsMixin } from 'sequelize';

class User extends Model {
  public getTeams!: HasManyGetAssociationsMixin<Team>;
}
User.init({}, { sequelize, modelName: 'user' });

class Team extends Model {}
Team.init(
  {
    name: DataTypes.STRING,
  },
  { sequelize, modelName: 'team' },
);

User.hasMany(Team);

(async function test() {
  try {
    await sequelize.sync({ force: true });
    const user = await User.create({ teams: [{ name: 'Bull' }, { name: 'Thunder' }] }, { include: [Team] });
    const teams = await user.getTeams();
    const teamDataValues = teams.map((team) => team.dataValues);
    console.log('teamDataValues: ', teamDataValues);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  } finally {
    await sequelize.close();
  }
})();
```

Execution result:

```sh
{ POSTGRES_HOST: '127.0.0.1',
  POSTGRES_PORT: '5430',
  POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 'testpass',
  POSTGRES_USER: 'testuser',
  POSTGRES_DB: 'node-sequelize-examples' }
Executing (default): DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "team" CASCADE;
Executing (default): DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "user" CASCADE;
Executing (default): DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "user" CASCADE;
Executing (default): CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "user" ("id"   SERIAL , PRIMARY KEY ("id"));
Executing (default): SELECT i.relname AS name, ix.indisprimary AS primary, ix.indisunique AS unique, ix.indkey AS indkey, array_agg(a.attnum) as column_indexes, array_agg(a.attname) AS column_names, pg_get_indexdef(ix.indexrelid) AS definition FROM pg_class t, pg_class i, pg_index ix, pg_attribute a WHERE t.oid = ix.indrelid AND i.oid = ix.indexrelid AND a.attrelid = t.oid AND t.relkind = 'r' and t.relname = 'user' GROUP BY i.relname, ix.indexrelid, ix.indisprimary, ix.indisunique, ix.indkey ORDER BY i.relname;
Executing (default): DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "team" CASCADE;
Executing (default): CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "team" ("id"   SERIAL , "name" VARCHAR(255), "userId" INTEGER REFERENCES "user" ("id") ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE, PRIMARY KEY ("id"));
Executing (default): SELECT i.relname AS name, ix.indisprimary AS primary, ix.indisunique AS unique, ix.indkey AS indkey, array_agg(a.attnum) as column_indexes, array_agg(a.attname) AS column_names, pg_get_indexdef(ix.indexrelid) AS definition FROM pg_class t, pg_class i, pg_index ix, pg_attribute a WHERE t.oid = ix.indrelid AND i.oid = ix.indexrelid AND a.attrelid = t.oid AND t.relkind = 'r' and t.relname = 'team' GROUP BY i.relname, ix.indexrelid, ix.indisprimary, ix.indisunique, ix.indkey ORDER BY i.relname;
Executing (default): INSERT INTO "user" ("id") VALUES (DEFAULT) RETURNING *;
Executing (default): INSERT INTO "team" ("id","name","userId") VALUES (DEFAULT,$1,$2) RETURNING *;
Executing (default): INSERT INTO "team" ("id","name","userId") VALUES (DEFAULT,$1,$2) RETURNING *;
Executing (default): SELECT "id", "name", "userId" FROM "team" AS "team" WHERE "team"."userId" = 1;
teamDataValues:  [ { id: 1, name: 'Bull', userId: 1 },
  { id: 2, name: 'Thunder', userId: 1 } ]
```

Check the data records in the database:

```sh
node-sequelize-examples=# select * from "user";
 id
----
  1
(1 row)

node-sequelize-examples=# select * from "team";
 id |  name   | userId
----+---------+--------
  1 | Bull    |      1
  2 | Thunder |      1
(2 rows)
```

Answer (score 0):

I just wrong pass "include". It should be:

```
   const userTeams = await user.getTeams({
          include: [
            {
              model: YourModel,
              as: 'alias specified in relation'
            }
          ]
        });
```